# How can I reference external JavaScript functions from Fine-Uploader callback?

Tags: aurelia, fine-uploader

I have the following code in my `user-profile.html`:

```
<template>
    <!--Fine-Uploader HTML is here
    ...-->
    <script>
        var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
            element: document.getElementById("uploader"),
            debug: true,
            cors: {
                expected: true
            },
            request: {
                endpoint: configOptions.baseUrl + '/api/assets',
                customHeaders: {
                    Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("aurelia_id_token")
                }
            },
            multiple: false,
            callbacks: {
                onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJSON){
                    updateProfile(responseJSON.displayUrl);
                }
            } 
        });  
    </script>
</template>
```

As you can see, I would like to invoke `updateProfile` upon successful completion of the upload. I'm getting as far as the `onComplete` callback, and am correctly parsing the JSON response object. The problem is that the `updateProfile` function is in a separate `.js` file, called `user-profile.js`.

I'm working in Aurelia, and this is the standard convention for creating an MVVM module, that is naming the files the same with `.html` and `.js` extensions. I'm not sure why they are not sharing scope in this case, but I'm getting the error:

```
Caught exception in 'onComplete' callback - updateProfile is not defined
```

I've also tried simply adding a standard script tag in the index file directly referencing the `.js` file but it doesn't work either, and seems like a bad idea anyway.

Any direction on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For third-party libraries, jQuery plugins, etc. it's always a good idea to encapsulate it within custom attribute or custom element. Also, as Ashley said, you cannot have `script` elements in a template.

`fine-uploader` is a good candidate for custom element. Here's a simplified version of one that I'm using in one of my projects:

```html
<!-- fine-uploader.html -->
<template>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Upload image</a>
</template>
```

```js
// fine-uploader.js
import fine from 'fine-uploader';
import {bindable, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(Element)
export class FineUploader {

  @bindable endpoint;            // URL to upload to
  @bindable params = {};         // Any additional upload params
  @bindable uploaded = () => {}; // Uploaded callback for consumers

  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  attached() {
    this.uploader = new fine.FineUploaderBasic({
      debug: true,
      button: this.element.children[0],
      callbacks: {
        onComplete: (id, name, response) => {
          if (this.uploaded) {
            this.uploaded(response);
          }
        }
      },
      request: {
        endpoint: this.endpoint,
        customHeaders: {
          'authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("aurelia_id_token")}`
        },
        method: 'PUT',
        params: this.params
      },
      scaling: {
        sendOriginal: false,
        sizes: [{ maxSize: 500 }]
      },
      validation: {
        acceptFiles: '.jpg,.png'
      }
    });
  }

  detached() {
    // Apparently, no destroy() method
    // https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1038
    //this.uploader.reset();
  }
}
```

This way, you can use the same component from multiple places. Here's the sample usage for your case:

```html
<!-- user-profile.html -->
<template>
  <require from="../resources/elements/fine-uploader"></require>

  <!-- ... -->
  <fine-uploader endpoint="/api/assets" params.bind="uploadParams" 
                 uploaded.call="imageUploaded($event)"></fine-uploader>
</template>
```

```js
// user-profile.js
export class UserProfile {

  activate(id) {
    this.uploadParams = {
      userId: id // And/or any other data you need to send with the image upload
    }
  }

  imageUploaded(response) {
    this.updateProfile(response.displayUrl);
  }

  updateProfile(url) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: This does the trick. Much more reusable to have this pulled out as an abstract service. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put `script` elements in an Aurelia template. You'll need to move the code in to your Aurelia VM, or in to a separate module you import in to the VM.

Comment: That was my first inclination, but I was unable to get the FineUploader object to load properly. I think that, it wants to bind to the `<div id="uploader" ></div>` further up in the template, but the script is executing before that actually loads so I get an `undefined` error on the `document.getElementById("uploader"),` line.